# Can’t run get semget to create semaphores in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I am running cygwin on windows 8, when I call semget function i get an error, function not implemented. Does anyone know how to make this work, any point in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/std-notes.html

> The XSI IPC functions semctl, semget, semop, shmat, shmctl, shmdt,
> shmget, msgctl, msgget, msgrcv and msgsnd are only available when
> cygserver is running.

so run the cygserver. It belongs to the `Cygwin` package

```
$ cygcheck -l cygwin | grep server
/etc/defaults/etc/cygserver.conf
/usr/bin/cygserver-config
/usr/sbin/cygserver.exe
/usr/share/doc/Cygwin/cygserver.README
```

Use `cygserver-config` to install the service.
After you can verify and start the service with:

```
$ cygrunsrv -Q cygserver
Service             : cygserver
Display name        : CYGWIN cygserver
Current State       : Stopped
Command             : /usr/sbin/cygserver

$ cygrunsrv -S cygserver

$ cygrunsrv -Q cygserver
Service             : cygserver
Display name        : CYGWIN cygserver
Current State       : Running
Controls Accepted   : Stop
Command             : /usr/sbin/cygserver
```

Comment: hmm maybe I never started the service, i ran the codog file and set export CYGWIN=server. Whats the command to start the service?

Comment: sorry config file

Comment: Thank you. I have confirmed the server is running, I now get invalid argument error on call mutex=semget(IPC_PRIVATE,0,IPC_CREAT)). But this soultion seems to have fixed my ability to use the function.

Comment: why 0 ? see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/semget.html