# Error "Function not implemented" in semget using cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin, semaphore

I am running following C program, using cygwin. Getting error 88 after the semget command.

Can someone help what needs to e done to get the semget working?

```
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   int semid;

   semid=semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,IPC_CREAT|0600);
   if (semid == -1){
        printf("ERRNO=%d",errno);
        printf(" %s",strerror(errno));
    }else{
        printf("ID = %d\n", semid);
    }
   return 0;
 }
```

I am getting following output when above program is run [image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64615621/can-t-run-get-semget-to-create-semaphores-in-cygwin

Comment: As per this link, I tried running cygserver-config, but giving error "/usr/bin/cygserver-config: line 181: cygrunsrv: command not found". How do I fix this?

Comment: ps: it compiles and runs without a problem on 'Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Windows'

Answer (score 1):

Use cygcheck to find the package:

```
$ cygcheck -p bin/cygrunsrv
Found 4 matches for bin/cygrunsrv
...
cygrunsrv-1.62-1 - cygrunsrv: NT/W2K service initiator (installed binaries and support files)
```

so you need to install the `cygrunsrv` package

After the installation and configuration of cygserver, you can run it with:

```
$ cygrunsrv -S cygserver
```

and with your program

```
$ gcc -Wall prova.c -o prova

$ ./prova.exe
ID = 65536

$ ./prova.exe
ID = 65537
```